# How to enable wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use the Rest API in my brother's wordpress news website but https://my-site.com/wp-json only returns `{"code":"rest_disabled","message":"The REST API on this site has been disabled.","data":{"status":403}}`
I asked my brother if he had disabled the rest api but he doesn't understand what i'm talking about.

Comment: May be something have to do with the theme, try searching for `rest_authentication_errors` action hook in function.php or try using default theme and see if you can access rest API url

Comment: This is my first time dealing with wordpress so i don't quite understand your point. What does this have to do with theme and where is the function.php file?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I solved it, it turns out the theme my brother was using for the site have disabled rest api by default in`functions.php`. All i had to do was to look in the file and comment out the code that disables the rest api.

Comment: `code that disables the rest api` - which is what?..

Comment: I figure it depends on the theme you use, which I why I did not mention it.

Comment: So at least tell us what was yours?